# CakePHP setting up dependent AJAX dropdown

Tags: ajax, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have done a lot of research, tried to apply a few different examples but it seems that nothing really works.

So I have the following 3 models: Customers, Projects and Events. Customers have many Projects and Projects have many Events.

While creating an Event, I would like a user to select a Customer from a dropdown list and then the user should be provided with a list of Projects that belong to the selected Customer. The closest I have got to is the following. I do not have experience with AJAX, so that really is a hard nut to brake.

Action in the Porject's controller:

```
    public function getbycustomer(){

    $customer_id = $this->request->data['Event']['customer_id'];

    $projects = $this->Project->find('list', array('conditions'=>array('Project.customer_id' => $customer_id), 'recursive' => -1));

    $this->set('projects', $projects);
    $this->layout = 'ajax'; 
}
```

View for this action is the following:

```
    <?php foreach ($projects as $key => $value): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And here is the snippets from the view for adding an event:

```
    echo $this->Form->input('customer_id');
        echo $this->Form->input('project_id'); 

//form continues and at the end of a page there is the AJAX call

    $this->Js->get('#EventCustomerId')->event('change', 
    $this->Js->request(array(
        'controller'=>'projects',
        'action'=>'getbycustomer'
        ), array(
        'update'=>'#EventProjectId',
        'async' => true,
        'method' => 'post',
        'dataExpression'=>true,
        'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
            'isForm' => true,
            'inline' => true
            ))
        ))
    );
```

Any help is much much appreciated as I do not even know the proper way for debugging it, so I could provide more valuable information.

Comment: At first glance your code looks right, you bind a change event to the dropdown and then fire a request to the action that fetches the data. Does your application's error log or the JS console say anything? Also, are you sure you have loaded the JsHelper? I don't think it's loaded by default.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but there is no error given. The JsHelper is loaded in the controller like this  _var $helpers = array('Form', 'Html', 'Session', 'Js');_

Comment: Ok. What is exactly your question?

Comment: Well the question is how to get it to run. 
I really need it, and would do everything to provide you with information if you need some more.

Comment: This is very vague -- what specifically is it doing that is not right?  What's the javascript it's producing?  A general tip is that AJAX is basically just fetching another webpage, then doing something with it once it's fetched.  So, navigate to the page you're getting with AJAX, and debug it as you would any other webpage.  It gets more complicated if the AJAX source is supposed to be requested through post, so I usually start with get regardless, then change it to post if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

go to [this](http://www.willis-owen.co.uk/2011/11/dynamic-select-box-with-cakephp-2-0/). this helped me to do the dependent drop down list. it provies a details step by step process.

Comment: you are my hero! I was looking for this for hours and I can't believe there's so few examples as clear as that article. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set autoRender to false otherwise it will try to render the template at app/View/Project/getbycustomer.ctp.  Also, you probably want to return or print JSON.  Ther are probably several ways to do this, but I have something similar that is working and the controller action is basically this:

```
public function getbycustomer() {
  $this->autoRender = $this->layout = false;
  $customer_id = $this->request->data['Event']['customer_id'];
  $projects = $this->Project->find('list', array('conditions'=>array('Project.customer_id' => $customer_id), 'recursive' => -1));
  $this->set('projects', $projects);
  echo json_encode(array('html' => $this->render('your_partial_template')->body())); // This template would be in app/View/Project/json/
}
```

Then in your Ajax call there should be a 'success' callback that handles the JSON returned:

```
success: function(data) {
  $('#EventProjectId').html(data.html); // assuming this an empty container
}
```

Also, unless your projects table is only two columns the result of your find is probably not what you're expecting.  Change it to

```
$projects = $this->Project->find('list', array('conditions'=>array('Project.customer_id' => $customer_id), 'fields' => array('id', 'name_or_whatever', 'recursive' => -1));
```

Then in your partial template you can use the form helper:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Projects.id', array('options' => $projects)); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I just cannot get it to work. No errors are given, but the dropdown is not filled. Let me know if you need any further information.